# ui - accordion does not work after empty() and append()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have Four DIVs and I call accordion function to it. It works fine initially. But it fails after I clear all the content and again append the FOUR DIVs.

Kindly take a look at the link
http://jsfiddle.net/p7vUk/2/

You will see that on clicking divA , divAA will slide toggle.
on clicking divB, divBB will slide toggle.

After you click the 'clear all' Button, the div=content is cleared and same four DIVS are appended, but the jquery accordion fails to work.

Answer (score 0):

The accordion styling and behaviour is defined upon creation. Looks like the accordion does not update when the content changes. Nor does there appear to be a method you can call to trigger an update.

Have you tried 'turning it off and on again'?

```
//change content, then:
$("#content").accordion("destroy");
$("#content").accordion({ ... your options ... }); //create it again
```

This may require more related work, such as setting the originally selected tab, etc.